# Flexible duct behind dryer looks a little sketchy

Tags: dryer, vent, ducts, washer

So we just noticed that the air flow in our house is always bad when we run the dryer. Looking behind the unit, we found a foily looking mess of a flexible duct behind the dryer. It looks almost like torn unstable piece of foil was just slapped on connecting the duct to the hole and it just flaps around. Is this normal? Or something I need to call for, or.. can I somehow fix this myself? Any help regarding this matter would help a ton. 
[image]

Comment: “air flow in our house is always bad”   What does that mean?

Comment: Bad air flow means when the dryer is on?   First look I would say that is the dryer vent - not sure but I think most places would allow flexible ducting like that for dryers since lint can build up and create a fire hazard

Comment: Yeah -- that looks like regular HVAC flex, not a dryer connector.  Is there a rigid exhaust port for the dryer in the wall or floor somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Part of your question is a matter of your prerogative and skill set, and part is very broad. Please do some reading into dryer venting and revise to ask a more specific question. If you're asking how to fix this, please revise to share more information about what happens outside our narrow view into the situation.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like standard flexible dryer duct to me. Pull your dryer out and it will probably be connected to the back of the dryer. I would look as there is probably a pipe connection that this flex duct fell off of. I don't think the pipe is a standard flex duct used for HVAC that has an inner and outer flex chamber with insulation in the middle. 
Look close at the bottom left the connection point to the vent may be right there. Connecting the pipe will help the problems you are experianceing when the dryer is running.